# control multiple XAML file through one code

Tags: wpf, xaml, ironpython

I have made 2 XAML files.

The first one is loaded when I open the program and it contains a button.

XAML (`WpfApplication4.xaml`):

```
<Window 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       Title="WpfApplication4" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="86" Margin="47,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The second XAML (called `addon.xaml`) contains a button and a list.

XAML (`addon.xaml`):

```
<Window 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       Title="addon" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="86" Margin="47,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" Click="Button2_Click"/>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="59" Margin="168,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="13" Margin="242,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23"/>
        <Label Content="test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="80,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My goal is to switch between the XAML files when I clicked the button in order to switch screens (now it contains only button and list but generally it should be a very different screen than the first one).

The .py looks as following: (**EDITED**)

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import Application, Window

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication4.xaml')

def Button_Click(self, sender, e):
    self.ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'addon.xaml')

def Button2_Click(self, sender, e):
    self.ui = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication4.xaml')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

And it manage to switch between the XAML however, when I click button2 to return to the original XAML (WpfApplication4) It says that there is already exists a variable named button (which is obvious because I cant change the button name every time it is clicked)

Is there a way to "delete" the memory of "self" so it wont remember the variables from the first time it was opened?

```
Could not register named object. Cannot register duplicate name 'Button' in this scope.
```

Thank you

Comment: The windows have to be different classes. What you want to do is have them share the same viewmodel, which is trivial.

Comment: any chance to explain more please? not sure how to use it.

Comment: [Here's an article about doing it with IronPython](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com.ar/2010/10/wpf-and-mvvm-in-ironpython.html). Skimming through it, it's got the basics you need. The name for that style of WPF programming is "MVVM", for "Model-View-ViewModel". I don't even know Python, myself.

Comment: thing is that in the example it changes only a property of textbox for example and not the whole window property.

Comment: You can use the same viewmodel instance with two different windows. Same viewmodel, different XAML. If you want to switch between XAML in the same window, write two different DataTemplates with the different XAML, and switch the window's ContentTemplate between them.

Comment: static property 'ContentTemplate' of 'ContentControl' can only be assigned to through a type, not an instance thats when I try to use:     def Button_Click(self, sender, e):
        Window.ContentTemplate = wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'addon.xaml')

Comment: What’s this LoadComponent stuff? You’re not reading. You’re writing random code without a clue what you’re doing.

Comment: thats what "reads" the components (button,list,textbox) from the xaml. its like xamlread

Comment: Define datatemplates as resources.